# Is it causing deployment failure when there are 2 nodeSelectors under spec field in Kubernetes Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am deploying this [example](https://github.com/kubeedge/examples/tree/master/kubeedge-counter-demo) using kubeedge. I am using minikube to run the cluster. I managed to deploy the cloud part of the demo but the edge part wouldn't be deployed. The pod status is stuck on containerCreating for so long. This is the [deployment file](https://github.com/kubeedge/examples/blob/master/kubeedge-counter-demo/crds/kubeedge-pi-counter-app.yaml) of the edge part and I am seeing two nodeSelectors under the spec field. could be that the problem please?

I tried to use only one of them (I deleted the first nodeSelector) but it still didn't solve my problem.
when I run describe pod command I get this:
[Describe pod command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiMFY.png)

When I check status from edge side:
[edge part status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am64d.png)

Comment: what do you see when you run `kubectl describe po` command against the Deployment's Pod? Please add the relevant output in your post as well.